# Multithreading to handling multiple incoming requests

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am new to python. And I have to write a listener/server which will handle requests coming from same network. So I am using `socket`. I will be getting request json from client, server/listener will do processing and return the result. Thats all what is going to happen. And there will be no back and forth communication between server and client.

The code looks something like this:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)    
server_address = ('localhost', 10000)            
sock.bind(server_address)    
sock.listen(1)

while True: 
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()

    while True:
        #read request data
        #process request 
        #reply response to **connection** object
        break  #continue waiting for new request
```

Now the issue is that until the current request's processing is done, server will not accept new request. I somehow have to perform processing and sending response reply in separate concurrent thread. I tried by encapsulating the processing logic in separate class `RequestHandler` extending the `Thread` class. I passed `connection` object to the instance of my custom class `RequestHandler`. 
I did something like this:

```
requestHandler = RequestHandler(deepcopy(connection))
requestHandler.daemon = True
requestHandler.start()
```

However here is where I have stuck. Can I pass same `connection` object to new instances `RequestHandler` spawned each time I receive new request? Deep copying as in above code gave me following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot serialize socket object
```

I am doing something absolutely wrong? Should I follow some different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to extend `Thread` class. The simpliest version is this:

```
import threading

def client_handler(connection):
    #read request data
    #process request 
    #reply response to **connection** object

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)    
server_address = ('localhost', 10000)            
sock.bind(server_address)    
sock.listen(1)

while True: 
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    threading.Thread(target=client_handler, args=(connection,)).start()
```

Now you may wrap your socket object into `RequestHandler` class if you wish, that's fine. But you can't copy sockets. Just pass a reference instead: `RequestHandler(connection)`. Why would you copy it anyway?

The reason it is not copyable is because it represents some system resource (i.e. the socket). If there were 2 objects pointing at the same resource then they would conflict with each other. And at C level it is extremely hard to synchronize pure file descriptors (sockets are simply numbers at C level) if there are multiple owners. So socket object is a sort of a unique "gateway" to the underlying file descriptor.

Comment: **(1)** so without copying will it be able to accept multiple incoming requests? What if I pass `connection` object reference to one thread and another request comes which assigns new instance to `connection`  variable in the line `connection, client_address = sock.accept()`? **(2)** Will a new connection object be created for each incoming request? **(3)** Also will my extending Thread class approach work fine? I believe `target=client_handler` does the same internally?

Comment: @Mahesha999 1) Variables in Python are pointers (or references). When you do `connection, client_address = sock.accept()` you don't copy or modify any object. You just assign new socket object to old `connection` variable. But the old `connection` **object** is not affected at all.

Comment: 2) No, there will be a new connection object for each new **connected** client. Generally client and server make this "deal": "now I'm connected to you over this pipe as long as it takes". One client may issue multiple requests. In your case though it seems that you want to close the connection after first request. So in your case the answer is yes. 3) Yes, it will work fine. It's just that there is no need for doing that.

Comment: seems that it is working, however I want to know what I am doing is indeed correct / standard or preferred approach or I should be doing in some other way.